# Tracking the slow - how to list all processes related to web-server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, web-server, performance-monitoring, optimization

I wanted to ask people in this community about administration of the Debian based web server - its a dedicated server, hosting a single website.

From time to time the web site is slowing down, on some occasions becoming unresponsive for a half-minute-few minutes period. The causes are always different, so I am fixing one thing - another thing goes wrong, and its getting weird trying to find all the wrong things one after another.

I want to have a way to track down all of the processes related to the web server - apache, nginx, mysql, php, whatever else. I guess I want to be able to understand what happens and why whatever is happening occurs - what causes the slow and etc. So, I am thinking up about the ways to track it all down.

So far, I have the following command to track running apache and nginx processes:

```
top -u www-data
```

I have found a way to join "tail" from several log files at once:

```
tail -f error_log1 -f error_log2
```

What I need is to find more instruments and the way to track errors better than just looking around logs. Could you suggest me detailed answers on what I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were any of the tools in my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other tools:

- mod_status for Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html)
- strace (if you can identify a process which is hanging / running slowly),
- xdebug profiling (if it's a PHP script) - see http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler
- mytop (or run watch -n 1 "mysql -e 'show processlist'")